# Need help on creating the most stable LED possible

Tags: led, circuit-design, noise, constant-current, led-driver

I am currently trying to make a circuit to drive an LED with smallest amount of fluctuation as possible.

Background: Using an LED and spectrometer together to analyze small molecules. I can use the spectrometer to record the intensity of a light over time and that is how I read noise in an LED. I have tried a variety of LED linear drivers, and I am sticking to 5mm LEDs. My circuit consists of one driver (right now im using MAX16815) and LED, and some bypass capacitors at the IN and OUT pins.

Questions:

With a DMM, I found that the current decreases/increases for 15-20 minutes before reaching a steady state.

-How can I reduce this phenomenon?

I have a 35-100mA output 3.5% accuracy LED driver with a max 100mA 5mm LED. So far, I have been working on breadboard to do testing and analysis so there could be a source of error in there. I use an external resistor to control the current output of the driver. It currently takes 15 minutes to reach any current I choose with a standard deviation of 0.007 mA. I want to reach a standard deviation of 0.001 mA just to be sure.

What can I do to reduce variations in the intensity of the LED?

Comment: "What can I add/replace in my circuit" that question is really easy to answer since we all know what is in your circuit...

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I guess the question I was really asking was whether I was in the right track to just using a single LED driver with a 5mm to get the best constant light source possible.

Comment: A good linear current source will provide better stability of the drive to the LED, but if you want that kind of stability you would really need some sort of feedback measurement of the light emitted itself. The issue is the temperature of the LED changes the emissions, you would need to close that loop to get fast and accurate steady state output.

Comment: A linear constant current source controlled by a photodiode feedback would be ideal here.

Comment: In addition: you might be able to keep the light flux constant with feedback, but if temperature changes then the spectrum of the LED will change, so you will also need to control the temperature.

Comment: @winny yup, provided the photodiode is thermally isolated from the LED.

Comment: @gommer indeed, solid heat sinking is critical too.

Comment: @Trevor_G I'm thinking crystal oven for the entire system.

Comment: I'm thinking beam sample and  PD closed loop system.

Comment: What's the problem with it reaching a steady state after 15 minutes? Many high precision measuring tools need much longer. Some DMM only specify full precision after 4 hours of warming up.

Comment: Closed loop control as I suggested, wont need that

Comment: A better question will have a spec.  Optical output stability error required within  x seconds is -xx dB from output at xx mA, presently getting xx with yy .

Comment: I will try to reword the question. Also, I haven't used photo diodes before; I will try to do some research.

Comment: Reworded the question!

Comment: I was involved in creating LED-based light sources intended as "lamp references" for optical work. Even if you have a perfect current source, LED output varies with temperature. So they must be operated at a stable temperature. We chose to heat them to about 75C using a closed loop control. That solved the temperature drift problem. But LEDs themselves aren't consistent; even those cut from the same wafer aren't. We had to pre-stress thousands of them, holding them at a stable temperature, running them with a current source for days, monitoring the optical output and logging results.

Comment: A few, a SMALL FEW, would actually gradually drift and then settle down to a stable behavior (in peak wavelength and intensity.) We chose those for the optical standards. But we threw away most of them, by far. At the time, we kept less than 1% of those tested because more than 99% of them simply weren't stable even over periods of hours. (We used a current source that cost us about $30k, yielded extremely accurate and stable currents, and had been calibrated to NIST traceable standards.)

Comment: Wow thanks for the input. I am thinking of controlling the temperature as well because the spectrometer I use also varies with temperature.

Comment: We tested the LEDs for much longer than a few days. Those that stabilized in less than two days, were then stable over much longer periods. Those that didn't stabilize within two days, never were reliable even after "baking for weeks." So we determined that we could tell what we needed to know within two days and used that as a selection cutoff.

Comment: @aznjeromeo I just think you are ASKING FOR TROUBLE here. It was very, very hard work. The idea was obvious. "Let's use LEDs as standard candles." How stupid we were.

Comment: @aznjeromeo We succeeded. But cripes. It sometimes seemed that we'd never figure it out.

Comment: @aznjeromeo I specialize in pyrometry and phosphor thermometry, as well as binning LEDs for industry. I have and use spectrophotometers here. I have and use tools like disappearing filaments, calibrated lamps (recal'd every few dozens of hours of use) and merc-argon lamps for frequency calibration of the spectro as well as intensity, etc. An optical table, lasers, lenses, and the rest are common tools of the trade, as well. I seriously think you are embarking on a long path ahead.

Comment: Voting to reopen this question, because it's actually quite an interesting challenge.

Comment: 0.001 mA standard deviation out of how much driving current?

Comment: at around 36mA.

Comment: For quicker thermal settling, solder large copper foil regions to the two LED pins, right at the package. One region should be GND, and have lots of vias to GND plane. The other lead should also be large, and overlay the GND plane to dump heat into the GND. The ThermalTau of 1cm^2 foil is 0.9 seconds. The ThermalTau of 10cm^2 coil (4" per side) is 90 seconds. The ThermalTau of 1 meter square of foil is 9,000 seconds; don't go there.

Answer (score 1):

Search for CC sink or source. Or use a LM317 as such from 5V for 20mA.

LED brightness is a function of current and long term, aging.

Voltage has a NTC so any temp rise will reduce voltage -x mV/'C so constant voltage or even PWM with CV will affect intensity.

Even temperature rise affects efficacy to some extent.
Consider multiple 20Cd <=30deg  LED's operating at <10mA. Consider temperature stability and short term aging or burn-in process.

Only use PD + R , not photo transistor and block all stray light.

What stability range do you need  from drift?  > 30dB?   > 60dB ?

How will you equalize emission curve?

Do you want to regulate output using dual PD detector in a  closed loop? That is best way.

One using beam split closed loop feedback, Two for sample output detector.     e.g. Using 1% emitter sample with fiberoptic.
( not shown )

I assume using Bragg Effect... then get plots like this.

[image]

However I might suggest PNJ4K01F  or AMS-302 Panasonic logarithmic light detector with optical compensation...maybe for comparison.